# Некоректный вывод скринов на майл с помощью MIMEImage

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Суть программы**: Каждые 10 сек отправлять на майл по одному скрину.

**Проблема**: Начиная со второй отправки, программа отправляет уже не одно, а два скрина, т.е. добавляет текущий скрин к предыдущему.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()


while True:
    pyautogui.screenshot('screen.png')
    img_data = open('screen.png', 'rb')
    image = MIMEImage(img_data.read(), name=os.path.basename('screen.png'))
    msg.attach(image)
    img_data.close()
    os.remove(os.path.basename('screen.png'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.ru')
    server.starttls()

    server.login(msg['From'], password)
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

    server.quit()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Из-за ''msg.attach(image)'' контент письма накапливается и отправляется сразу куча писем. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Исправьте отступы в коде и покажите как объявляете msg

Comment: @n1tr0xs Подправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним из решений будет пересоздание `MIMEMultipart` в цикле, но придется заново заполнять его поля:

```
while True:
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    ...
```

---

Однако, посмотрев исходники увидел недокументированный способ в `Lib\email\message.py`:

```
    #
    # Payload manipulation.
    #
    def attach(self, payload):
        """Add the given payload to the current payload.

        The current payload will always be a list of objects after this method
        is called.  If you want to set the payload to a scalar object, use
        set_payload() instead.
        """
        if self._payload is None:
            self._payload = [payload]
        else:
            try:
                self._payload.append(payload)
            except AttributeError:
                raise TypeError("Attach is not valid on a message with a"
                                " non-multipart payload")
```

**Не советую этим пользоваться**, т.к. в других версиях или реализациях питона этого может и не быть.

Использование такое:

```
while True:
    if msg._payload:
        msg._payload.clear()
    ...
```

Comment: Пересоздание MIMEMultipart помогло, а вот как эти пэйлоады работают, я так и не понял

Comment: `MIMEMultipart` внутри себя хранит поле `_payload` (это список), и при вызове `attach` вы в этот список добавляли значения, поэтому и копилось к каждым циклом. Поэтому, решением может быть очистка списка `_payload` на каждой итерации

Comment: Ааа, вот теперь понял!